# Configure TFS 2012 to Build All Solutions Under Directory

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

To prevent unexpected build breaks and test failures, We have been using gated check ins. This works very well for our core solutions, and has helped improve our quality.

As part of our overall architecture, we have a certain section of our code with many micro-services, each of which is a new solution.  New solutions are added to this part of the code base regularly. These are important parts of the system, and I need to make sure they get compiled as part of a gated check in without the chance for developer error.

Is there a way to configure TFS to find ALL solutions under a certain path and include them in a gated check in build?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not without modifying the build process template, which is almost never a good idea. The new build system in TFS2015 does allow that, however.

Comment: TFS 2015 is fully suported for production use.

Comment: How would I modify a build process template?  I am not ready to move to TFS 2015 a it is still not a stable release.

Comment: I strongly, strongly recommend not modifying build process templates. They are nearly impossible to debug, maintain, and upgrade. It's awful.

Comment: Gated Builds in TFS 2015, at least with update 1, must be done with XAML builds. These do not allow wild cards unfortunately. Therefore do not allow **\*.sln to build all solutions.

Comment: I wish I could delete or edit comments. I found that I can use wild cards with TFS 2015 XAML builds. The path must be typed in, rather than using the File open dialog.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2015 vNext builds allow wild cards to search for all solutions. I haven't had success getting this to work with Visual Studio build steps, which you would need, but it works well with NuGet Installer and other build steps. We will not see gated builds in vNext builds until we get update 2 see [TFS feature timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx)